# how to know if it's email or username inputed

Tags: php

Hello everyone i want to ask question my html form, requires to input username/Email that you can put.
Then it searches by username or email if in database that account exists if yes process.
**The script works, but only with email.**

My problem is how to identify in input field is the user written an username or email? Now it checks both but for some reason it dosen't detect username only email typed.

```
function getUserEmailExist( $input )
    {
    global $database;

        if( preg_match( '/^[a-z0-9]+([_\\.-][a-z0-9]+)*@([a-z0-9]+([\.-][a-z0-9]+)*)+\\.[a-z]{2,}$/i', $input ) ) {
            $type = 2;
            $get = $database->checkExistRecovery( $input, $type );
        }

        if( preg_match( '/[^0-9A-Za-z]/', $input ) ) {
            $type = 1;
            $get = $database->checkExistRecovery( $input, $type );
        }

        if( $get ) {
            $this->updateRecover( $input, $type );
        } else {     
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: So the problem is that your second regex doesn't work? What would you like it to detect?

Comment: For your username check, you are checking for a negative `^` character set.  ie, it cannot be `[0-9A-Z-az]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move your email if statement below.

Because if the input is an email, it's going to match the second preg match anyway.
So you're overwriting your $type variable.

Fixed.

```
    function getUserEmailExist( $input )
    {
        global $database;

        if( preg_match( '/[A-Za-z0-9]+/', $input ) ) {
            $type = 1;
            $get = $database->checkExistRecovery( $input, $type );
        }

if( preg_match( '/^[a-z0-9]+([_\\.-][a-z0-9]+)*@([a-z0-9]+([\.-][a-z0-9]+)*)+\\.[a-z]{2,}$/i', $input ) ) {
            $type = 2;
            $get = $database->checkExistRecovery( $input, $type );
        }

        if( $get ) {
            $this->updateRecover( $input, $type );
        } else {     
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hmm, let me try. But i already tried that way, maybe this time it will work. Nope it dosen't work, still the same maybe i did something processing it? but i don't really think, becouse with email it works maybe only with type

Comment: Yep it worked, don't really understand why, becouse what you told me i did it just a minute ago, yes i replaced the first was username then email but still didin't work, maybe had some mistake in mine code when copied your it worked, thanks.

Comment: @karolis if you want to know why, read the comment on your question ;)  you used a negative character set, when he updated the code he removed the `^` from within the username check set.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want your second regex to be `/[A-Za-z0-9]+/`. You are currently looking for anything that doesn't contain those characters.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you care about all that validation logic?  I can't see your actual DB queries, but it seems you could easily do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE email = ? OR username = ?
```

Where ? would be the email or username value.

Comment: Possibly password recovery, so he knows which record to pull to allow a change, etc.  Though I think it should still be done with `username =? OR email=?` and then prepare the value twice in to that statement.

Comment: Yeah, i know that myself there two reasons i don't do that:
first - coding something that needs a bit more security.
secound - i already check database if exists or not by making them seperate by $type

example: if type == 1
search username
if type == 2
search email

Comment: @Jon Absolutely, a prepared statement is preferable here.  I do think it is important to look at each email/password and username/password combo however.  You can't just do `WHERE (email = ? OR username = ?) AND password = ?`.

Comment: @MikeBrant agreed completely for logging a user in - I didn't see a password being dealt with and assumed it was to find a username or email to then get the email of and send the user a password recovery link or similar - I hadn't assumed it was for authentication purposes.  ^^

Comment: @karolis I understand that that is your current approach, but you are enforcing validation logic in trying to determine what query to use.  This logic should exist when the data is being inserted and not necessarily when the data is being compared to the database. You now have to handle another edge case. What if the value passed doesn't match either regex (like say the username has an underscore in it)? If you are going to validate this data both on insert and lookup, you have two places in your code to maintain the logic (or the need to refactor it out to a standalone class/function)

Comment: @Jon Yeah looking at it again you may be right that there is no password in this case. I have updated answer.

Comment: @karolis To complete my above thought.  Having this validation logic here really gives you absolutely no benefit.  Having it there isn't going to help you match a record in the database any better.

Comment: if it dosen't match it return false, it contains about five functions more with checking by email/user if exist, updating and creating new pw, sending email, checking in recovery.php if it returns true do something else say you entered incorrect data. :)
P.S it's for filter purpose to clean the data i received from user. :)

Comment: Mike Brant if you insist i will upload all functions etc related to recover password it would be lovely to know what you think about it. :)

Comment: @karolis You might think about posting such to codereview.stackexchange.com or similar to get feedback. Like personally, if you were a developer on my team, I would question the logic of actually calling your `UpdateRecover()` method from within this method.  This method is named `getUserEmailExist()` and IMO should do just that and only that (verify if the user exists via email/username and return the user id to the caller). The caller could then decide whether to trigger the `UpdateRecover()` based on the response.